# Run automatically through function

Tags: javascript

The following code works when you click on the individual links, but I also want to let it automatically run through the content.

Javascript:

```
var kopjeC = 1;

function kopje(kopjeC){
    if(kopjeC == 1){
        document.getElementById('textB').innerHTML = 'Home';
        document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
        document.getElementById('2').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('3').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('4').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
    }
    if(kopjeC == 2){
        document.getElementById('textB').innerHTML = 'Lactatiekundige';
        document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('2').style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
        document.getElementById('3').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('4').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
    }
    if(kopjeC == 3){
        document.getElementById('textB').innerHTML = 'Consult';
        document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('2').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('3').style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
        document.getElementById('4').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
    }
    if(kopjeC == 4){
        document.getElementById('textB').innerHTML = 'Verhuur/verkoop';
        document.getElementById('1').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('2').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('3').style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById('4').style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
    }
}
```

How can I, for instance, go to the next subject (`kopjeC` value) after 5 seconds?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWFG9/5/)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through your function, use `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    kopje(kopjeC)
    kopjeC++
    if (kopjeC === 5){
        kopjeC = 1;  
    }
}, 1000);
```

This will run `kopje()` every 1000 milliseconds. Once `kopjeC` = 5, it restarts to the beginning.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/JWFG9/8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` for it:

```
var kopjeC = 0;

function kopje(kopjeC){
  // your function
}

setInterval(function() {
    kopjeC = kopjeC < 4 ? kopjeC + 1 : 1;
    kopje(kopjeC);
},5000);
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWFG9/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the setInterval js function. Something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (++kopjeC == 5) {
      kopjeC = 1;
  }
  kopje(kopjeC);
}, 5000);
```